# Alexander Hamilton Rap

Tags: word, humor

From [genius.com](https://genius.com/Jacksfilms-alexander-hamilton-lyrics):

> “Alexander Hamilton” is a song released by Jack Douglass, better known by his Youtube channel name, Jacksfilms.
>
> He wanted to come up with the worst costume for Halloween 2016. His costume is made to depict “A guy dressed up as Alexander Hamilton who hasn’t seen the show Hamilton but thinks he knows one of the songs but totally doesn’t but just goes with it”

Here's a video for anyone interested:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EoVheg5AolU

After familiarized yourself with the lyrics, why don't you continue the song by filling the lines below? It gets harder and harder as you go, so partial answers are encouraged!

**EDIT**

From the response of some people, the hints seems to be too broad. I put some constraints on the answers.

- All the answers are meant to be 1-word. Except (7), which is a 2-word answer.
- > (8) and (9) are supposed to be locations

> Alexander Hamilton
>
> Alexander Hamilton
>
> ---
>
> Got yourself a problem
>
> He can Alexander handle it
>
> Donated all his revenue
>
> Alexander _____________ (1)
>
> ---
>
> Try to emulate Squidward
>
> Alexander _____________ (2)
>
> Went to France to visit his friend
>
> Alexander and ___________ (3)
>
> ---
>
> See himself at the baseball game
>
> Alexander _____________ (4)
>
> Scored high on the SAT
>
> Alexander got _____________ (5)
>
> ---
>
> Dang he sings very good
>
> Alexander ____________ (6)
>
> He just got a foot taller!
>
> Thanks Alexander's ____________ (7)
>
> ---
>
> Supporting the Hoosier
>
> Alexander in ____________ (8)
>
> Help creating Sigma Nu
>
> Alexander in ___________ (9)
>
> Yo, I dedicate this song to Alexander Hamilton, the greatest president in the wooorrld

Answer (score 8):

--NEW GUESSES--

(5) Scored high on the SAT

> Alexander got **1510**
> 1510 out of 1600 is pretty high, and it rhymes

--CORRECT--

(8) Supporting the Hoosier

> Alexander **BLOOMINGTON**
> Bloomington, IN - stadium where the Hoosiers play

(9) Help creating Sigma Nu

> Alexander **LEXINGTON**
> Lexington, VA - headquarters of Sigma Nu

Comment: that is correct :)

Comment: The rhymes come in pair

Comment: Ah, I thought they all **loosely** rhymed with 'Hamilton' though.

Answer (score 5):

I really think this is a bit broad. There are a lot of answers that can fit the 'three-ish syllables and vaguely has the same cadence (not even rhyme) as 'Hamilton' That said, let's guess a few...

(1) Donated all his revenue

> Alexander Samaritan.

(2) Try to emulate Squidward
??

(3) Went to France to visit his friend

> Alexander Parisian

(4) See himself at the baseball game

> Alexander Jumbotron

(5) Score high on the SAT

> Alexander Collegian

(6) Dang he sings very good

> Alexander Musician

(7) He just got a foot taller!

> Alexander Towerin'

(8) Supporting the Hoosier

> Alexander Football Fan

(9) Help creating Sigma Nu
??

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer.

(1) Donated all his revenue

> Alexander philanthropist.

(2) Try to emulate Squidward

> 

(3) Went to France to visit his friend

> 

(4) See himself at the baseball game

> Alexander in the grandstand.

(5) Score high on the SAT

> 

(6) Dang he sings very good

> Alexander sings soprano jams.

(7) He just got a foot taller!

> Alexander's a growin' man again.

(8) Supporting the Hoosier

> Alexander Indiana man.

(9) Help creating Sigma Nu

> Alexander paddlin'.

Comment: I'm afraid it's all wrong :( The majority of answers are one word and the relations are not as crazy as you make it to be :)

Answer (score 3):

I know they're not all right, but I had fun coming up with them:

(1)

> Got yourself a problem
>  He can Alexander handle it
>  Donated all his revenue
>  Alexander **philanthropist**.

(2,3)

> Try to emulate Squidward
>  Alexander **clarinet**
>  Went to France to visit his friend
>  Alexander and **baguette**

(4,5)

> See himself at the baseball game
>  Alexander **jumbotron**
>  Score high on the SAT
>  Alexander got **nothing wrong**

(6,7)

> Dang he sings very good
>  Alexander **sings falsetto**.
>  He just got a foot taller!
>  Thank Alexander's **new stilletos**.

(these two already solved by [hagfy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66639/41358))
(8,9)

> Supporting the Hoosier
>  Alexander **Bloomington**.
>  Help creating Sigma Nu
>  Alexander **Lexington**.

Comment: Why was this accepted? There are multiple two-word answers.

Comment: @ScottMilner I'm not actually sure myself...

Comment: It was a mis-click :) (2) and (4) are correct

Answer (score 1):

(2) Try to emulate Squidward

> Alexander Management

(3) Went to France to visit his friend

> Alexander and Lafayette (3)

Comment: (3) is correct :)